# Unsigned Integer Division ARM Cortex-M0+ Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, division, cortex-m

Hi all I am new here but anyway here is my problem:
I am trying to write a subroutine for unsigned integer division in Assembly but I really cannot figure it out. If anyone could show me how to do it, that would be great.

I will call the subroutine DIVU. R1 will be the dividend. The divisor will be in R0. The quotient is going to be in RO and the remained in R1.

Basically, I am trying to make something like this: R1÷R0=R0remainderR1

If R0=0, I want to leave the input parameters unchanged and set the C flag when it returns. Otherwise, I just want to clear the C flag. I do not want to change any other registers' values after returning.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is there any reason this is hard?  ARM has a division instruction, doesn't it?   single-step through the asm for a C function that does it, and see what's in the libgcc functions that gcc emits calls for.  (https://godbolt.org/g/rao3lh).  Or does Cortex-M0 leave out the division instruction?

Comment: I am pretty sure that they leave out the division function

Comment: So are you asking how to implement division manually?  The "related questions" sidebar already has several with promising titles that look like they're about ARM division.  The other part of the question is just a matter of using push/pop to save/restore any regs you want your function not to modify.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so, I will check those out. And alright thanks. I am new to using Assembly so I need all the help I can get lol

Comment: When you're totally new to something, every problem seems unlike every other problem, and mysterious.  But that doesn't make it a good SO question. :(  If you still have any questions left after checking out the other ARM division questions, and learning to use push/pop to get some scratch registers, then edit this.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your time.

I have done some more looking around and it appears I need to turn the following into Assembly. 

Quotient =0;
while(Dividend>=Divisor) {
 Dividend=Dividend -Divisor;
 Quotient =Quotient +1;}

Remainder=Dividend . If no one gives me Assembly code, I will add my solution when I come up with it

Comment: @JasonR - Is this just a learning exercise, or is the intent to create a practical (reasonably fast) division routine? Repeated subtraction would be slow. Including a left shift on each step would help. ARM provides fast division routines in libraries for the processors that do not include a divide instruction.

Comment: This does not need to be anything extremely fast. It is for more of my learning experience, so the repeated subtraction will be fine.

Comment: Repeated subtraction with a left shift isn't that much more complicated. Here is a link to [software integer division](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/software-integer-division/), click on download pdf file. The pdf file includes basic and advanced algorithms.

Comment: rcgldr, I just saw your comment. I have posted what I have come up with so far as an answer, but I will also look into what you suggested. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have come up with so far. What do you all think? Does it seem like it will work? Constructive criticism for a newbie would be nice, as well as some examples of what to change it to. Thanks :)

```
DIVU
      CMP   R1,#0       ;compares R1 to 0
      BEQ   AnsZero     ;if R1=0, it branches to AnsZero (the final answer will be 0)
      CMP   R0,#0       ;compares R0 to 0
      BEQ   EndFlag     ;if R0=0, it will go to the end to set C flag
      PUSH  {R3}        ;saves R3 so it can used as a counter for quotient
      MOV   R3,#0       ;sets R3 to 0
While CMP   R0,R1       ;start of while loop 
      BLT   EndWhil     ;Branches to end of while when dividend < divisor, otherwise goes through loop
      SUB   R1,R1,R0    ;R1=R1-R0 , dividend=dividend-divisor
      ADD   R3,R3,#1    ;R3=R3+1, quotient=quotient+1 (init is zero, so 0+1=1 if one successful loop)
      B While       ;continues loop
EndWhil MOV R0,R3       ;R0=R3, the register that had the divisor gets the quotient
      PULL  {R3}        ;R3's original value is returned
      B Return      ;goes to end of subroutine labeled return
EndFlag PUSH {R0}       ;saves original R0 value
      PUSH  {R1}        ;saves original R1 value
      MRS   R0,APSR     ;this line and the next few down all set the C flag without changing other flags
      MOVS  R1,#0x20    
      LSLS  R1,R1,#24   
      ORRS  R0,R0,R1    
      MSR   APSR,R0
      PULL  {R1}        ;gets original R1 value
      PULL  {R0}        ;gets original R0 value
      B Return      ;goes to end of subroutine
AnsZero MOV R0,#0       ;sets R0=0 because R1=1, 0/X=0r0
      B Return      ;goes to end of subroutine
Return  BX  LR      ;returns from subroutine
```

I apologize if the code is not displayed correctly, I am new to this so I am still trying to figure out the best way to copy it to the browser and show properly here.

Comment: [codereview.SE] is a good place for code that you believe to be working.  There isn't much asm activity over there, but it's better than asking for feedback in a self-answer.  (There's nowhere for anyone to post more than a comment).

Comment: However, from a quick look, your code has some pretty obvious style/performance errors:  ARM's PUSH instruction takes a list of registers.  Never use two back-to-back PUSH instructions when you could push multiple regs with one insn.  [Same for POP](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489g/Cihcadda.html).  (Does PULL even assemble?).

Comment: It's ok to have multiple `BX LR` return instructions in your function.  You don't need to, and shouldn't, `B RETURN` unless you want to have all the exit paths share a bunch of common epilogue code.

Comment: It's normal to arrange a loop so the conditional branch is at the end.  That reduces the instruction-count by one (removing the unconditional branch).  Sometimes you need to test if the loop should even run once before falling into it, or jump to the test at the end, if you can't guarantee that it should always run at least once (do{}while() style).

Comment: You don't need the S suffix on multiple flag-setting instructions.  Or does thumb-2 only allow the short encoding with the sets-flags version?  Anyway, instead of manually modifying APSR, why not `subs r0, r0, #1` / `mov r0, #0` to set the carry flag?  (You know r0 is 0 on entry to that block, so you don't need to save it, and can restore it with a mov immediate 0)  It looks like you could then combine more of that exit path with the AnsZero block, since they both just zero R0 before returning.

Comment: I will give code review a try! thanks. and i didnt even think of that way you recommend for setting the C flag, that is much shorter and a lot easier and doesn't require the pushing or any registers.

Comment: as far as the push/pull goes: pushi will make one list, and pull does not work lol, i meant to use pop.

Comment: ping me (use `@peter` in your comment) with a link to your CR question when you post it.  I'm already writing an answer to this question since I can't read inefficient code without needing to improve it. :P  I'll post it over on CR if you have the question ready before I finish (and incorporate my comments here).  BTW, not sure what you mean about PUSHI "will make one list".  Yes, exactly.  So you can save a list of registers, and restore the same list (or a different list!).  It's common to `push {R4, LR}` and then return with `pop {R4, PC}`, because ARM exposes the program counter as a reg.

Comment: Ah, it appears I was using push and pop incorrectly then. here is a link to it and I'll mention you over there @PeterCordes http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141388/unsigned-integer-division-arm-cortex-m0-assembly

Comment: @PeterCordes all issues with the other post have been resolved, it is now back up. Let me know what you think about it http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141388/unsigned-integer-division-arm-cortex-m0-assembly?noredirect=1#comment264936_141388